Is it possible to make coloured text output in Python using specified RGB values rather than ANSI Escape Codes?
I was recently making an random number generator in python and I was wondering is it possible to make coloured text output in Python using specified RGB values rather than ANSI Escape Codes?
I wanted to make it so that the greater the number generated the stronger the colour / the colour changes. I was wondering if I could do this using a library or some other way other than ANSI Escape Codes as they only provide a limited range of colours I think its 16? Instead I would like to be able to set the RGB values from 0 - 255. Is this possible in python?
Thank you :)
